# How to search for rows containing a substring?

Tags: mysql, odbc

If I store an HTML TEXTAREA in my ODBC database each time the user submits a form, what's the `SELECT` statement to retrieve 1) all rows which contain a given sub-string 2) all rows which don't (and is the search case sensitive?)

---

Edit:  if `LIKE "%SUBSTRING%"` is going to be slow, would it be better to get everything & sort it out in PHP?

Comment: blob is case-sensitive, where text is case-insensitive

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, you can always try `WHERE textcolumn LIKE "%SUBSTRING%"` - but this is guaranteed to be pretty slow, as your query can't do an index match because you are looking for characters on the left side.

It depends on the field type - a textarea usually won't be saved as VARCHAR, but rather as (a kind of) TEXT field, so you can use the [MATCH AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) operator.

To get the columns that don't match, simply put a NOT in front of the like: `WHERE textcolumn NOT LIKE "%SUBSTRING%"`.

Whether the search is case-sensitive or not depends on how you stock the data, especially what COLLATION you use. By default, the search will be case-insensitive.

#### Updated answer to reflect question update:

I say that doing a `WHERE field LIKE "%value%"` is slower than `WHERE field LIKE "value%"` if the column field has an index, but this is still considerably faster than getting all values and having your application filter. Both scenario's:

1/ If you do `SELECT field FROM table WHERE field LIKE "%value%"`, MySQL will scan the entire table, and only send the fields containing "value".

2/ If you do `SELECT field FROM table` and then have your application (in your case PHP) filter only the rows with "value" in it, MySQL will also scan the entire table, but send all the fields to PHP, which then has to do additional work. This is much slower than case #1.

Solution: Please do use the `WHERE` clause, and use `EXPLAIN` to see the performance.

Comment: ah but if you are caching the data or otherwise pushing it, then the sql expense would only happen once. then it comes down to which is quicker at filtering the set ;]

Comment: Garet: absolutely, and it's these trade-offs you have to take into account. In most cases, filtering at the database itself has an advantage because 1/ you don't have to send the extra data over the network 2/ the database was built for filtering, has extra indexes, and 3/ the dbms can optimize the data/indexes based on the queries it receives... but ymmv :)

Answer (score 5):

Info on MySQL's full text search. This is restricted to MyISAM tables, so may not be suitable if you wantto use a different table type.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Even if `WHERE textcolumn LIKE "%SUBSTRING%"` is going to be slow, I think it is probably better to let the Database handle it rather than have PHP handle it. If it is possible to restrict searches by some other criteria (date range, user, etc) then you may find the substring search is OK (ish).

If you are searching for whole words, you could pull out all the individual words into a separate table and use that to restrict the substring search. (So when searching for "my search string" you look for the the longest word "search" only do the substring search on records containing the word "search")

Comment: Hello, question is talking about substring. (Doesn't full text work only on word boundaries?)

Answer (score 1):

I simply use `SELECT ColumnName1, ColumnName2,.....WHERE LOCATE(subtr, ColumnNameX)<>0`
To get rows with `ColumnNameX` having the substring.

Replace `<>` with `=` to get rows `NOT` having the substring.