# Searching substrings from a large set of strings

Tags: string, search, data-structures

Is there a space efficient data structure that can help answer the following question:

> Assume I have a database of a large number of strings (in the
>   millions). I need to be able to answer quickly if a given string is
>   a substring of one these strings in the database.

Note that it's not even necessary in this case to tell which string it is a substring of, just that it's a substring of one.

As clarification, the ideal is to keep the data as small as possible, but query speed is really the most important issue. The minimum requirement is being able to hold the query data structure in RAM.

Comment: _Space_ efficient would be storing the strings and nothing else – of course that does not make the _search_ efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to go about this is to avoid using your Java application to answer the question.  If you solve the problem in Java, your app is guaranteed to read the entire table, and this is in addition to logic you will have to run on each record.

A better strategy would be to use your database to answer the question.  Consider the following SQL query (assuming your database is some SQL flavor):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE column LIKE "%substring%"
```

This query will return the number of rows where 'column' contains some 'substring'.  You can issue a JDBC call from your Java application.  As a general rule, you should leave the heavy database lifting to your RDBMS; it was created for that.

I am giving a hat tip to this SO post which was the basis for my response: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4122193/how-to-search-for-rows-containing-a-substring

Comment: I did not say anywhere that the text files are in an SQL database. The application in question is a security tool and choosing the internal representation here can be anything that works. Queries are done on data in live packet streams, so using a database with it's latency is not an option. Oh, and the language everything is written in is C++.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are highly compact structures, so for regular English text it is unlikely that you will find any other kind of structure that would be more space efficient than strings.  You can perform various tricks with bits so as to make each character occupy less space in memory, (at the expense of supporting other languages,) but the savings there will be linear.

However, if your strings have a very low degree of variation, (very high level of repetition,) then you might be able to save space by constructing a tree in which each node corresponds to a letter. Each path of nodes in the tree then forms a possible word, as follows:

```
 [c]-+-[a]-+-[t]
           +
           +-[r]
```

So, the above tree encodes the following words: `cat`, `car`.  Of course this will only result in savings if you have a huge number of mostly similar strings.