# Search where column value is within a string

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this database table:

```
| id | name |    city   |
+----+------+-----------+
| 10 | test | anza      |
| 11 | fish | riverside |
```

I want to find items whos city name is included in a string like:

> anza city
>
> riverside county

How can I find items whose city name is included in my strings using MySQL? In other words, which cities are included in the string 'anza city'? This should return id 10.

It seems the opposite of LIKE in MySQL.

Comment: Can you put your current query here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the opposite of `LIKE`. I imagine the reason you feel that way is because you're used to seeing something like this:

```
WHERE columnName LIKE 'someString';
```

However, you can still use this but you need to use some manipulation on the column. If you want to check that the column name is within your string, just add wildcards at the front and back, and use `LIKE` in this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE 'anza city' LIKE CONCAT('%', city, '%');
```

Note that the value with the wild cards will go on the right side of the like. If you said `CONCAT('%', city, '%') LIKE 'anza city'` nothing will be returned.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c95e80/4) example.

**EDIT**

Here is more information regarding searching for a [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122193/how-to-search-for-rows-containing-a-substring).

---

*Fun fact, this is my 300th Stack Overflow answer! I hope it helps you.*