# Search for specific keyword in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm almost new to mysql.

I wanted to write a query to search for specific keywords in a column where keywords are separated by the comma. but as I use the following code, it only returns the rows where I only have that specific keyword, not in combination with any other keywords.

In Table q16, I'm looking for a way to select rows that have my keyword in the "Area_of_concern" column, no matter if it's combined with other keywords or not:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `q16` 
 WHERE area_of_concern like '%more education is needed%'
```

Here's an input example:

q16_id  area of concern

```
1   more education is needed
2   more enforcement, change in strategy
3   change in strategy
4   more education is needed, change in strategy
5   transportation issue, more enforcement, more education is needed
```

Where I'm looking to get the rows with the keyword "more education is needed". So I should see row 1, 4,5 in the output

Comment: Please provide (add to your question by using [Edit]) some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: could you please add input and expected output in your question  ?

Comment: Here's a sample input: q16_id area of concern
1 more education is needed
2 more enforcement, change in strategy
3 change in strategy
4 more education is needed, change in strategy
5 transportation issue, more enforcement, more education is needed

Comment: Have you considered using FULLTEXT Search?

Comment: I created a table named survey: create Table survey(
    survey_id INT unsigned not null,
    keyword varchar(128)
    );    from q16 Join survey
    where survey.keyword=q16.Area_of_Concern
       ON survey.keyword NOT IN ('more education', 'more enforcement in place')
    GROUP BY q16.Area_of_Concern                                Then I get this error: Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT IN" at position 125)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a table where you have one column for keywords and one column for where those keywords are used: a foreign key for the q16 table in your case.

It will work much faster that way.

As for your question it is a duplicate of this one here, I believe.

[How to search for rows containing a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122193/how-to-search-for-rows-containing-a-substring)

A quick try: try using double quotes instead of single ones, as in some systems, single quotes don't allow for escapes (special characters) inside them.

Comment: Right. This is basic normalisation. Stuffing discrete data into arbitrary columns that don't enforce integrity makes for slow and error-prone databases. What if someone made a typo in that keyword in that freely editable string, for example?